# SyntaxError: expected an indented block (Python)

Tags: python

I now there are already a lot of posts and discussion about the subject which I have read and still I'm getting this error and I totally can't understand WHY? I double checked all the indentations which are 4 spaces, no TAB used. I mean I'm sure (IMHO) everything looks all right to me. Thanks.

```
def the_math_sample():
    if 9 + 12 == 10 and not 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
    elif 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        print 'Happy Days'
    else:
        print 'False example'
```

> SyntaxError: expected an indented block, line 3

---

I've corrected my example to:

```
def the_math_sample():
    if 9 + 12 == 10 and not 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        print ('Correct')
    elif 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        print ('Happy Days')
    else:
        print ('False example')
```

Now it's all right. Thanks to everyone for the fast response and all the answers!

Comment: What should happen in that first case?

Comment: You can't use `if` without anything inside it, if it is something to do later, use `pass` like this: `if something: pass`

Comment: No statement between 'if' and 'elif'.

Comment: Are we facing Y2K all over again? `if 9 + 12 == 10 and not 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:` What is  the purpose of this?

Comment: Jeez, you guys are ruthless. I'm not saying this is a great question, but it definitely isn't obvious why such code is not syntactically valid from a beginner's point of view.

Comment: Upvote from me, as agreeing completely with Vincent. Also the question is stated clear, the code is reproducible, and it is a quite condensed example. It is a total beginners' issue, but actually not so easy to google if you don't know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I appreciate that.

Comment: roganjosh, it`s just simply for learning purposes to get Boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

This is how the code should look:

```
def the_math_sample():
    if 9 + 12 == 10 and not 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        pass
    elif 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        print('Happy Days')
    else:
        print('False example')
```

When you start a `if` statement, you have to have something nested inside of it. The `pass` keyword just means "don't do anything".

Comment: You're right, I'm on mobile forgot to indent the function. fixed.

Comment: SyntaxError on print 'Happy Days' ,no?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The syntax makes me assume it's 2.7, which the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Pikaroo I`m using Python 3.5

Comment: Python 3, i'm using https://repl.it/languages/python3 to run code

Comment: I edited the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It wants code for what to do if the initial `if` is true; that is the `indented block` it expects.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
def the_math_sample():
    if 9 + 12 == 10 and not 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        pass
    elif 2 < 5 or 5 != 5:
        print("Happy Days")
    else:
        print("False example")
```

After your first if statement you should put something to do  or in python you can put a pass statement that doesn't do nothing.

Comment: If you call the_math_sample() the result should be Happy Days

Comment: You would have been better to place the `pass` line under the `if` and indent it. At the moment it's hard to spot your change (especially without an explanation) and the layout is not standard python.

Comment: @Tony you are right and i apologies for it.